# HTTP put is not saving data to the server api using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ma trying to update data in the server using restful api. when i click save buttion . I get the massage that data is updated successfully but It is not saving updating data to the server.

I am passing the function updateop to update the data in the server using ng-submit

```
<tbody><tr ng-repeat="user in names | filter:filters.search| filter: filters.searchdd | filter:customFilter(unit)">
<td>



                    <a  href="#"   ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"> {{ user.name }}</a>
                     <div ng-show="collapsed">

                <form name="unitUpdateForm" ng-submit="updateop(user)">
                                        <!-- Name -->
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <!-- Name -->
                                            <label >Name</label>
                                            <input ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />

                                            <!-- TODO: Add more attributes -->
                                            <label >Short name</label>
                                            <input ng-model="user.shortName" placeholder="Short name" class="form-control" />


                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                                                value="Save" />
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Here is my angular js file where i am calling the function.

```
 $scope.updateop = function(user) {

    var apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/organisationUnits/";

    console.log(user);

    // Setup request
    var request = $http({
        method: "put",
        url: apiUrl + user.id + '.json',
        data: user,
    });

    // Perform request
    request.success(function(data) {
        // TODO: Some kind of feedback? Angular automatically updates template.
        //alert("Update success!");
        console.log(data);
        //Refreshes the data from db with the newly updated unit
        init(); 
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        alert("Update error");
        init();
    });

};
```

It give me alert update sucess . It is not Updating Data on the server.

Comment: you need to check the server side code. If there are exceptions while saving the data. Also if there is any exception handling done on the server side, you ajax might still return a success.